# Magento2 checkout gives "Cannot read property 'items' of undefined - totals.js:22"

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2

When checking out out as a logged in user, adding my address in step one and clicking to proceed to the next step, I get the following error;

> Cannot read property 'items' of undefined` on line 22 in pub/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/en_GB/Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals.js

I'm running **Magento 2.2.2**

Comment: have you fix resolve this issue?

Comment: i had the same issue, but it was a bad files compiled problem.

Comment: I am facing the same issue i have removed  var,generated,pub/static/ folder still no luck